# arcpy join csv files to raster attribute table

Tags: arcpy, raster, attribute-table, attribute-joins, error-000840

In arcpy, I'm trying to join an list of .csv files with data of emissions per country, with the attribute table of a raster in order to make lookup tables later on. So far this is my script:

```
ras_countries = "E:\\eco_services\\data\\EU_28"

arcpy.env.workspace = "G:\\AIR_QUALITY\\paper\\GAINS_emission\\emission_gains"
landuse_tables = arcpy.ListTables ("emiss*")
for landuse in landuse_tables:
    tableViewName = landuse [6:-4]
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(landuse, tableViewName)
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(ras_countries, "cou_abb", tableViewName, "cou_abb")
```

But I always get the same error message:

ERROR 000840: The value is not a Table View.
ERROR 000825: The value is not a layer or table view
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
WARNING 000970: The join field COU_ABB in the join table EU_28 is not indexed. To improve performance, we recommend that an index be created for the join field in the join table.

I also tried converting the .csv files to .dbf but still no success.

any suggestions?

Failed to execute (AddJoin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your raster to a raster layer prior to joining fields to its attribute table. Use the [Make Raster Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Raster_Layer/00170000006t000000/) tool:

favorite

```
ras_countries = "E:\\eco_services\\data\\EU_28"
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(ras_countries, "ras_layer")

arcpy.env.workspace = "G:\\AIR_QUALITY\\paper\\GAINS_emission\\emission_gains"
landuse_tables = arcpy.ListTables ("emiss*")
for landuse in landuse_tables:
    tableViewName = landuse [6:-4]
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(landuse, tableViewName)
    arcpy.AddJoin_management("ras_layer", "cou_abb", tableViewName, "cou_abb")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was considering only the tables and not the raster...However, I still didn't manage to make the join I always get the same error:"ERROR 000728: Field COU_ABB does not exist within table
Failed to execute (AddJoin)." Is it because when converting to raster layer the raster attribute table disappears?

Comment: No, the attribute table is still there in the layer, your code works with my data. Are you sure the field is also there in the table view you try to join?

Comment: Dear GISGe, I finally got the solution: the problem was that the field name of the raster layer was "COU_ABB" and not "cou_abb" so the addJoin_management didn't work because was looking for exactly the same name. I solved the problem using arcpy.JoinField_management that accepts different field names.

Comment: Dear GISGe, I finally got the solution: the problem was that the field name of the raster layer was "COU_ABB" and not "cou_abb" so the addJoin_management didn't work because was looking for exactly the same name. I solved the problem using arcpy.JoinField_management that accepts different field names. The issue is that fields in raster layer are always in capital letters...

Comment: Great! If you use Join Field you don't even need to convert your data to layer or view first. I was not sure you have access to it since it requires an Advanced license.